# Twitter user_timeline JSONP. No response

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter, xmlhttprequest

## Solved

The problem is that Twitter now (stupidly) requires OAuth even for public data. An easy enough workaround is to have a local php script which OAuths and gets the data and access that with Ajax as opposed to Ajaxing twitter directly.

---

<strike>I'm currently trying to pull user timelines from twitter using the Reqwest JavaScript library.  However when I do so the request is considered successful but no data is retrieved and the console displays a GET error. The code im trying is as follows:</strike>

```
$.domReady(function () {
    
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitter',
        type: 'jsonp',
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });

})
```

Comment: Twitter API version 1 is deprecated and may no longer be supported (can't remember the exact date). You need to use API 1.1

Comment: I've tried 1.1 and it's also unsuccessful. Post updated

Comment: I faced a similar problem and I think you must use OAuth now before being able to make calls to the Twitter API, are you already doing that? I work with C#.net and used LinqToTwitter to solve this

Comment: also, I think the syntax has changed a bit (i.e it wouldn't be a simple as changing 1 to 1.1), will try and find an example for you

Comment: @Tyler Tried accessing direct through chrome and it says "Bad authentication..." so it's likely and OAuth requirement. Pretty pathetic that you need to OAuth public tweets but I'll give it a shot. And it is jus a case of using 1.1 instead of 1. Checked the API docs :)

Comment: yep! I went through all of this around a month back, really annoying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just updated a [plugin](http://zkniebel.github.com/jquery-twitter-feed/) of mine to work with the Twitter 1.1 API. Unfortunately, per Twitter's urging, you will have to perform the actual request from server-side code. However, you can pass the response to the plugin and it will take care of the rest. I don't know what framework you are running, but I have already added sample code for making the request in C#, and will be adding sample code for PHP, shortly.

Comment: I'm personally not using jQuery but will set this as the accepted answer regardless as Im sure it will solve the issue for a lot of people. Thanks :)

Comment: Not a problem - if you need help with making a customized, vanilla JS version let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass parameter `jsoncallback`.
http://jsfiddle.net/CCTKa/

I just got Bad Authentication data error.

Answer (score 0):

If we want to, we can still parse their pages and reimplement at least a bit of lost functionality with pure client-side JS.

What we need is: a CORS proxy that can deal with HTTPS pages (the only I know is YQL APIs) and the knowledge of how the information is retreived on their public pages.
Keeping this in mind, we can fetch, for example, recent 20 tweets from a user, as I did in the demo: http://jsbin.com/agejol/1 (click "Edit in JSBin" to view the code)

P.S. I know this may violate their policy but I care about it just as much as they cared about us when they dropped all their client-side APIs.